# Can't understand purpose of method overriding

Tags: oop, overriding

I can't understand the purpose of method overriding in OOP.

Why don't just put the overrided method another name, and if you need this specific new method you just call it by his new name, and not the name inherited for the parent class?

Comment: I think there are plenty of articles available to describe this in detail. A very common place would be wikipedia here is the reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding

Check example provided in any of the language to understand it in more detail or google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very useful purpose of method overloading is to support a clean interface across multiple classes that all derive from a common parent.

Here's an example. Consider a three classes called Integer, Decimal, and Fraction that all derive from the parent class Number. Now Number might have a method called Number.increment() that makes the Number bigger by 1. In the Number class, this could be as simple as taking the internally stored value and adding 1 -- something like x = x+1. For Integer and Decimal, it would probably be fine to keep this function. But for the Fraction class, we might need to do something fancier -- Fraction would probably have two internally stored values for the numerator and denominator, x and y, and we have (x/y)+1 = (x+y)/y. So we could then overload Fraction's 'increment' method to handle this case.

From the point of view of someone (perhaps myself!) using my code, this is nice. I don't have to remember that Fractions are different 'under the hood'. All Number objects feel the same when I interact with them -- I simply use the 'increment()' function. That's what I meant earlier by saying member overloading helps make a 'clean interface'.

If we did as you suggest and wrote a different function -- call it Fraction.otherIncrement() -- then I would have to remember to call Fraction.otherIncrement() instead of Fraction.increment(). Not so clean. And if I accidentally forget and call Fraction.increment() instead, then I'm really in trouble because this function really doesn't even make sense for the Fraction!

All of this has to do with the more general ideas of *encapsulation* and *polymorphism* that are at the heart of object-oriented programming. Briefly (and these aren't perfect definitions, by any means!), encapsulation refers to the idea that the details of how something works should be hidden from the user. And polymorphism means that different objects can still be interacted with in the same way. Both of these ideas make programming large projects much more reliable and greatly facilitate the process of building on someone else's work. Over-riding methods is a key way to achieve these goals.